# Spring JPA - Substitute Data Source on Runtime

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

Is it possible to switch jpa data source on runtime?
I have registers some data source on my apps, but I need to switch data source on runtime.

I am building a web application to show summary information of multiple application (white-label). Each application has its own database with same structure. I have read access to all this database.

Then this web application has its own database to store authorization. Which database is accessible by each user. Some user has access to multiple databases.

When users access the information from certain database, first this web application needs to check if this user has authorization to this database. If authorized, then repository will select data from this database. But of course, this thing need to change data source first.

Note: I don't have permission to create table on each apps database, read only. And I want authorization to database stored in one table. So, it will easier to do modification or create form to manage it.

This is my snippet code

Class CurrentTenantIdentifierResolverImpl : to get current tenant id. Previously I use subdomain to define which datasource id will used.

```
@Component
public class CurrentTenantIdentifierResolverImpl implements CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver {

private static final String DEFAULT_TENANT_ID = "test";

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * 
 * @see org.hibernate.context.spi.CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver#
 * resolveCurrentTenantIdentifier()
 */
@Override
public String resolveCurrentTenantIdentifier() {

    String tenant = DEFAULT_TENANT_ID;

    /*
     * RequestAttributes requestAttributes =
     * RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes(); if (requestAttributes != null) {
     * ServletRequestAttributes attr = (ServletRequestAttributes)
     * RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes(); HttpServletRequest request =
     * attr.getRequest(); tenant = UrlParser.getIlibrary(request);
     * TenantContextHolder.setTenantId(tenant); }
     */

    // The tenant is stored in a ThreadLocal before the end user's login information
    // is submitted for spring security authentication mechanism. Refer to
    // CustomAuthenticationFilter

    return StringUtils.isNotBlank(tenant) ? tenant : DEFAULT_TENANT_ID;
}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * 
 * @see org.hibernate.context.spi.CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver#
 * validateExistingCurrentSessions()
 */
@Override
public boolean validateExistingCurrentSessions() {
    return true;
}
}
```

This class is to get appropriate data sources

```
@Component
public class DataSourceBasedMultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl
    extends AbstractDataSourceBasedMultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Autowired
private Map<String, DataSource> dataSourcesMtApp;

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * 
 * @see org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.spi.
 * AbstractDataSourceBasedMultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl#selectAnyDataSource(
 * )
 */
@Override
protected DataSource selectAnyDataSource() {
    return this.dataSourcesMtApp.values().iterator().next();
}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * 
 * @see org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.spi.
 * AbstractDataSourceBasedMultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl#selectDataSource(
 * java.lang.String)
 */
@Override
protected DataSource selectDataSource(String tenantIdentifier) {
    return this.dataSourcesMtApp.get(tenantIdentifier);
}
}
```

This class is to store all datasources

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties({ MultitenancyProperties.class, JpaProperties.class })
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class MultiTenancyJpaConfiguration {

@Autowired
private JpaProperties jpaProperties;

@Autowired
private MultitenancyProperties multitenancyProperties;

/**
 * Builds a map of all data sources defined in the application.yml file
 * 
 * @return
 */
@Primary
@Bean(name = "dataSourcesMtApp")
public Map<String, DataSource> dataSourcesMtApp() {
    Map<String, DataSource> result = new HashMap<String, DataSource>();
    for (DataSourceProperties dsProperties : this.multitenancyProperties.getDataSources()) {

        DataSourceBuilder<?> factory = DataSourceBuilder.create().url(dsProperties.getUrl())
                .username(dsProperties.getUsername()).password(dsProperties.getPassword())
                .driverClassName(dsProperties.getDriverClassName());

        result.put(dsProperties.getTenantId(), factory.build());
    }
    return result;
}

/**
 * Autowires the data sources so that they can be used by the Spring JPA to
 * access the database
 * 
 * @return
 */
@Bean
public MultiTenantConnectionProvider multiTenantConnectionProvider() {
    // Autowires dataSourcesMtApp
    return new DataSourceBasedMultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl();
}

/**
 * Since this is a multi-tenant application, Hibernate requires that the current
 * tenant identifier is resolved for use with
 * {@link org.hibernate.context.spi.CurrentSessionContext} and
 * {@link org.hibernate.SessionFactory#getCurrentSession()}
 * 
 * @return
 */
@Bean
public CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver currentTenantIdentifierResolver() {
    return new CurrentTenantIdentifierResolverImpl();
}

/**
 * org.springframework.beans.factory.FactoryBean that creates a JPA
 * {@link javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory} according to JPA's standard
 * container bootstrap contract. This is the most powerful way to set up a
 * shared JPA EntityManagerFactory in a Spring application context; the
 * EntityManagerFactory can then be passed to JPA-based DAOs via dependency
 * injection. Note that switching to a JNDI lookup or to a
 * {@link org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean} definition
 * is just a matter of configuration!
 * 
 * @param multiTenantConnectionProvider
 * @param currentTenantIdentifierResolver
 * @return
 */
@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean(
        MultiTenantConnectionProvider multiTenantConnectionProvider,
        CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver currentTenantIdentifierResolver) {

    Map<String, Object> hibernateProps = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    hibernateProps.putAll(this.jpaProperties.getProperties());
    hibernateProps.put(Environment.MULTI_TENANT, MultiTenancyStrategy.DATABASE);
    hibernateProps.put(Environment.MULTI_TENANT_CONNECTION_PROVIDER, multiTenantConnectionProvider);
    hibernateProps.put(Environment.MULTI_TENANT_IDENTIFIER_RESOLVER, currentTenantIdentifierResolver);

    // No dataSource is set to resulting entityManagerFactoryBean
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean result = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    result.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { Instansi.class.getPackage().getName() });
    result.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
    result.setJpaPropertyMap(hibernateProps);

    return result;
}

/**
 * Interface used to interact with the entity manager factory for the
 * persistence unit.
 * 
 * @param entityManagerFactoryBean
 * @return
 */
@Bean
public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean) {
    return entityManagerFactoryBean.getObject();
}

/**
 * Creates a new
 * {@link org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager#JpaTransactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf)}
 * instance.
 * 
 * {@link org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager} is the
 * central interface in Spring's transaction infrastructure. Applications can
 * use this directly, but it is not primarily meant as API: Typically,
 * applications will work with either TransactionTemplate or declarative
 * transaction demarcation through AOP.
 * 
 * @param entityManagerFactory
 * @return
 */
@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
    return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
}
}
```

To map database config

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties("multitenancy.mtapp")
public class MultitenancyProperties {

private List<DataSourceProperties> dataSourcesProps;

public List<DataSourceProperties> getDataSources() {
    return this.dataSourcesProps;
}

public void setDataSources(List<DataSourceProperties> dataSourcesProps) {
    this.dataSourcesProps = dataSourcesProps;
}

public static class DataSourceProperties extends org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties {

    private String tenantId;

    public String getTenantId() {
        return tenantId;
    }

    public void setTenantId(String tenantId) {
        this.tenantId = tenantId;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Are you using repository? How are you querying the database? why can't you create multiple datasources and use it based on the information

Comment: I am successfully create  multi datasources (multitenancy). But I need to switch the datasource based on condition inside my code logic. And I don't know how to do it yet.
Yes, I use repository. Database mean connection to all database (data sources)? I create it by register all connection in application.properties. As how multitenancy in commonly. I folllow this one https://sunitkatkar.blogspot.com/2018/04/building-saas-style-multi-tenant-web.html

Comment: do you have separate repository classes for each database right? How r u configurin datasources?

Comment: No, I use the same repository class